# 360 degree image rotating in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms, I want to rotate an image as 360 degree. This image rotates with animation constantly at run time. Also, this image has 6 versions of different views. Think about like rotating a glass by hand.

I try this one but it is useless:

```
<Image Source="glass.png" RotateToY="30"/>
```

Comment: You can review the features on this page. I do not think there's a class for 360 degrees but you can write your own class with these properties.  https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/rotation/

Comment: I try these  methods but I dont want exactly them. I think you are right about writing my own class.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the Image "Rotation" property and change it via a background thread if needed and add animate to it via `RotateTo` in order to control the rotation speed and start/end point speeds:

```
async Task RotateImageContinously()
{
    while (true) // a CancellationToken in real life ;-)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (image.Rotation >= 360f) image.Rotation = 0;
            await image.RotateTo(i * (360 / 6), 1000, Easing.CubicInOut);
        }
    }
}
```

Bounce:

[image]

Linear:

[image]

Cubic:

[image]

Comment: It's perfectly fit.

Comment: The rotation task won't stop executing even though the app navigates to another page.  The only way to stop it is to exit the app

Comment: @Patrick That code is just an example, you would need to cancel/exit that `while` loop: `while (true) // a CancellationToken in real life`

Comment: @SushiHangover okay I see what you mean.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [a similar question and answers on Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43068/can-visualelement-rotateto-be-used-to-create-an-infinite-rotation-animation).

The accepted answer suggests this:

```
private async Task RotateElement(VisualElement element, CancellationToken cancellation)
{
    while (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await element.RotateTo(360, 800, Easing.Linear);
        await element.RotateTo(0, 0); // reset to initial position
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this package will help you
https://github.com/ilievmark/Basil.Behaviors/tree/master/sample/BehaviorsSample/Pages/Animations

You can use something like this

```
           <d:CycledAnimationDecorator Cycles="10">
                <h:SequenceHandlerExecutor WaitResult="True">
                    <s:RotateAnimation Length="800" Rotation="360" />
                    <s:RotateAnimation Length="0" Rotation="0" />
                </h:SequenceHandlerExecutor>
            </d:CycledAnimationDecorator>
```